# How to convert dictionary to dataframe with keeping order of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys being the order of products, from 0 to 5 for example. I want to convert the dictionary to df and also keep track of the id of product. I would like to have a column being 'product_id' and to have the values of the keys:0,1,2... And the other columns to be the ones from the dictionary's values: ID, Category, Electronics...

```
 {0: {'ID': 'ABCDS', 'CATEGORY': 'Electronics', 'PRICE': '1234', 'Currency': 'Dollar'}}
```

I tried to convert the dict like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.values())
```

But in this way I lose the keys which keep track of the products. How to also have a column name in the df with the values being the order from the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {0: {'ID': 'ABCDS', 'CATEGORY': 'Electronics', 'PRICE': '1234', 'Currency': 'Dollar'}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index").rename_axis("product_id").reset_index()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   product_id     ID     CATEGORY PRICE Currency
0           0  ABCDS  Electronics  1234   Dollar
```

As an alternative use [`DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{"product_id" : key, **d } for key, d in data.items()])
```

**Output**

```
   product_id     ID     CATEGORY PRICE Currency
0           0  ABCDS  Electronics  1234   Dollar
```